# .htaccess redirect old URLs to new URLs, http to https, non-www to www?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a somewhat tall order for redirecting URLs for a new version of an existing site. Currently, I'm forcing www and redirecting all links with the following structure:

http://www.example.com/username

using the following .htaccess rules:

```
#Force www in all links
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#This rule allows for vanity URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^agents/(.*) /members.php?$1 [l]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /members.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

The new version of this site will be using https site-wide, and the new URL structure that should redirect any old links will look like this:

https://www.example.com/first-directory/second-directory/member

**NOTE:** That third rule would disappear on the new site since pretty URLs are being handled under the hood by the framework I'm using.

Taking site-wide SSL into consideration, what's the best way to achieve permanent redirects to the new URLs?

Comment: What is the original URL that you to be redirected to `https://www.example.com/first-directory/second-directory/member`?

Comment: The original URL that third rule was converting into a pretty URL looks like: http://www.example.com/members.php?member, but as mentioned that's a non issue since that won't exist anymore. The old format of http://www.example.com/username is what I need to detect and convert to the new URL.

Comment: So you just want to insert `/first-directory/second-directory/` before `username`  and make it `https://`?

Comment: Ideally yes, for any existing links that match the http://www.example.com/username format.

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /first-directory/second-directory/$1 [L,R=302]
```